# Unable to copy azure database

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

We had successfully been using New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy in an Octopus Deploy step to copy our production database into a staging database.  It recently stopped working with the following vague error:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy : 40687: The operation cannot be performed on the database 'databaseMcDatabase' in its current state.
At C:\Octopus\Work\20170623140313-4142\Script.ps1:9 char:1
+ New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -CopyDatabaseName $DatabaseName -DatabaseName Source ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Replication.Cmdlet.NewAzureSqlDatabaseCopy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being insufficient space in our Azure Elastic Pool.  I discovered I could copy a smaller database without any issue, and when I removed the -ElasticPoolName option from the command I was able to copy the 60GB db also.

Comment: Thank you for posting back, can you mark this as an answer so that others can benefit from the learning.